# Session handling in Symfony and AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, symfony, session, authentication

I need some advice for my Login authentication. My web-app has two parts:
Frontend is AngularJS and Backend Symfony. I was able to implement Authentication in Backend, I can login there and get the correct User from the database with the correct role.

Now I would like to create a session and return it to the Frontend. But how do I do that exactly? I'm thinking about returning the session with a Json Web Token to Angular. Is this the right approach? And what do I have to implement in my Angular Controller to save that session correctly?

Thank you in advance!

Here's my code:

**Backend (Symfony)**

```
        class SecurityController extends Controller {
/**
         * @Route("/login", name="login_form")
         */
        public function loginAction(Request $request) {
            $session = $request->getSession();
            // get the login error if there is one
            $error = $session->get(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
            $session->remove(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);

            return new JsonResponse($session);
        }
```

**Here's my Angular-Frontend**

```
var cardCollectionControllers = angular.module('cardCollectionControllers');cardCollectionControllers.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.login = function() {
        $http({
            method  : 'POST',
            url     : 'http://localhost:8080/card_collection_backend/web/app_dev.php/login',
            data    : encodeURIComponent('username=' + $scope.username +'&password=' + $scope.password),
            headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        })
            .success(function(data) {
                //what to do here?
            });
    };}]);
```

Comment: JWT is a good way to go and you get bundles for symfony to work with them. Save it in Angular however you want (ie local storage). You could use a http interceptor in angular to automatically add the token to all requests (and handle token renewal, etc)

Comment: Thanks for advice! Btw is the code in Backend correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Json Web Token is corresponding to your need.

See [LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle) to setup a real JWT authentication in your Symfony2 app (very simple to use).

And for the client-side, a really good package exists for angularJS called [Satelizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer)

There is a very good example implementing those two tools with Symfony2 and AngularJS :

https://github.com/slashfan/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundleSandbox